# Play video using YouTube Iframe API after ajax call in mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, mobile, youtube-api

I am building an application that a user enter a certain text and click a button. Based on that text I do a service call and fetch a youtube video. For now I am using YouTube Iframe API, and after I fetch the data from the server I load and play the video.

The thing is that this doesn't work on a mobile device, because mobile devices only allow me to play a video from javascript if I am in a callback from a user input, but since I need to fetch the data from the server first, I can't play the video from the user click callback, I need to do this on the ajax call callback.

Do anyone knows any workaround on that?

**EDIT:** Just to make it more clear I will give an example. Is not my actual code but it illustrates well the issue

```
//Playv is a button on the screen
$("#playv").click(function(){
    /*This function works on mobile without issues
    since this is a callback for a user input*/
    player.playVideo(); 
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797", function(data){
         /*This function doesn't work here since this is the 
         callback of the ajax call and not the user input */ 
         /*I want to make this works somehow*/
         player.playVideo();
     })
});
```

Comment: These might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837686/youtube-iframe-api-through-ajax and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850956/jquery-ajax-load-and-youtube-api-iframe

Comment: Thank you for posting, but it doesn't. My issue is related to mobile devices don't allow me to play a video from javascript, except when thi js code is triggered by a user action (like clicking a button)